# Mark packets with iptables based on TTL and length

Tags: iptables

**I can't match packets on the TTL**

I want to mark the packets that, after being routed, have a TTL less than 10 with the following command:

```
iptables -v --table mangle -A POSTROUTING -o h_0_0-eth0 -m ttl --ttl-lt 10 -j MARK --set-mark 10
```

But I keep getting the same error:

```
MARK  all opt -- in * out h_0_0-eth0  0.0.0.0/0  -> 0.0.0.0/0   TTL match TTL < 10 MARK set 0xa
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

I am using **iptables v1.4.21**. I assume that it is not a problem of loaded modules, since the verbose output recognizes the TTL match.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be the problem?

Comment: does `modprobe iptable_mangle` help?

Comment: Not really... **lsmod** gives me the following modules:

nf_nat_irc, nf_log_ipv4, nf_log_common, ipt_MASQUERADE, nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4, iptable_nat, nf_nat_ipv4, nf_nat, xt_mark

Comment: then all this looks strange as your command succeeds for me on kernel 3.19.8 (Fedora distro)

Comment: I tried to install the newest iptables (v1.6.0) and the problem remains. I am trying to do that in a VM (debian/jessie64 vagrant box). However, the command works fine in my host machine...

Comment: I think the problem is that I don't have the x_tables module compiled in my kernel. This module is the one that allows the iptables extensions to work.

The output to grep "x_tables" /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.dep is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from the fact that the netfilter extensions were not included in my patched version of the Linux kernel.

So I had to re-compile the kernel and activate various configuration options, such as:

```
# Xtables targets
#
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_AUDIT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CHECKSUM=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CLASSIFY=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CONNMARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CONNSECMARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_DSCP=y

# This one provides the TTL target
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_HL=y 
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_HMARK=y
...
```

and now everything is working!